# Importing tensorflow module using full path

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I import the tensorflow module using the full path where I installed it?

I'm trying something like this, but I'm not sure which file has the tensorflow module as the tensorflow installation added many py files.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/python/tensorflow')

from ? import tensorflow
```

Note: I installed tensorflow in a different folder using pip install tensorflow --target:'/python/tensorflow' because I don't have access to the Python folder with the libs which is configured in the system variables.

Comment: Try to use the solution given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: This is what's using. But I don't know the exact file which contains the tensorflow module